# Google Maps API being called from iOS App

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an iOS app that generates a map with markers on it and polylines. We were waiting for purchasing to approve the Google Maps for Work subscription and so, in the meantime I was using my personal Google account to generate the api keys and enable the api's we needed (Directions and GeoCode) so we could work on development.

Everything worked fine. Now we have our for Work subscription and I am trying to switch over to the new keys. My manager created the project and I was added to it using my gmail account. He initially generated the keys, the iOS SDK key is ok but the Browser key is not functioning. I call this url and get this error:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=231%20Parkview%20Court,%20Edwardsville,%20IL&key=AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

The APIs are enabled:

[image]

If I flip back to my personal API key it works fine. Help me Google engineers, you are my only hope! :)